# Run script hole time on VPS server

Tags: vps

Is it possible to create a script that is always running on my VPS server? And what need i to do to run it the hole time? (I haven't yet a VPS server, but if this is possible i wants to buy one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, there are many methods to get your expected result.

## Supervisord

[Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) is a process control system that keeps any process running. It automatically start or restart your process whenever necessary.

**When to use it:** Use it when you need a process that run continuously, eg.:

- A queue worker that reads a database continuously waiting for a job to run.
- A node application that acts like a daemon

## Cron

Cron allow you running processes regularly, in time intervals. You can for example run a process every 1 minute, or every 30 minutes, or any time interval you need.

**When to use it:** Use it when your process is not long running, it do a task and end, and you do not need it beign restarted automatically like on *Supervisord*, eg.:

- A task that collects logs everyday and send it on a gzip by email
- A backup routine.

Whatever you choose, there are many tutorials on the internet on how configuring both, so I'll not go into this details.